# Enhance this simple JS show/hide script

Tags: javascript

I have this:

JS

```
  function unhide(divID) {
var item = document.getElementById(divID);
if (item) {
  item.className=(item.className=='hidden')?'unhidden':'hidden';
}
  }
```

CSS

```
 .hidden { display: none; }
 .unhidden { display: block; }
```

HTML

```
  <a href="javascript:unhide('learnHTML');">See tips and tricks</a> 
  <p><div id="learnHTML" class="hidden"> my text</div></p>
```

And it all works well, but when the link "See tips and tricks" is clicked and related text is displayed, I would like change the text to "Hide tips and tricks". I tried several things and could not figure it out. I would prefer pure JS with no jQuery.

http://jsfiddle.net/hNVHJ/6/

Comment: I recommend to learn about proper event handling/binding: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by adding an event listener on the link. First you should give the link tag an id like 'tips-tricks-toggle' so you can easily access it with javascript.

```
<a href="#" id="tips-tricks-toggle">See tips and tricks</a>
<p><div id="learnHTML" class="hidden"> my text</div></p>
```

Now, just above the `</body>` tag add a `<script></script>` in this script tag you can put this javascript. The reason why it needs to be after all the html in the body is so that the javascript doesn't run before the elements are loaded on the page.

```
(function() {
    var button = document.getElementById('tips-tricks-toggle'),
        div = document.getElementById('learnHTML');
    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
        this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML === 'See tips and tricks' ? 'Hide tips and tricks' : 'See tips and tricks';
        div.className = div.className === 'hidden' ? 'unhidden' : 'hidden';
    });
})();
```

What it does is it stores the two elements into variables for easy access. Then adds an event listener for the click event on the link tag. The callback function is run when the link tag is clicked.

Here's a js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hNVHJ/11/

This JS fiddle is an enhancement of the above code http://jsfiddle.net/hNVHJ/13/ It allows for multiple links and multiple hidden divs.

Comment: yes but your solution seem to be valid only for one specific element ID. With the script I mentioned is possible to show/hide any element simply by adapting link and div ID.

Answer (score 2):

There are better ways to do this but I assume this is what you want.
Use onclick instead of href:

HTML:

```
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="unhide(this,'learnHTML');">See tips and tricks</a> 
    <p><div id="learnHTML" class="hidden"> my text</div></p>
```

JS:

```
function unhide(elem,divID) {
    var item = document.getElementById(divID);
    if (item) {
        if(item.className == 'hidden'){
              elem.innerText = elem.innerText.replace('See','Hide');
              item.className= 'unhidden';
        }
        else
        {
              elem.innerText = elem.innerText.replace('Hide','See');
              item.className= 'hidden';
        }
    }
  }
```

Here's your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9fKLm/)

Comment: I tested your fiddle but he don't work because nothing appear when I click